# grails application tomcat deployment

Tags: tomcat, grails, war, application-loader

I have a Spring Boot grails application. I'm able to run the application using 'run-app' and also i can successfully deploy the war file in local tomcat server.

But when i deploy the application in remote tomcat server, the Application Loader is not running and the deployment was successful. When I hit the URL, it is showing 404 exception. I cannot see any error in the tomcat error log. Only difference i could find was,

**Local Tomcat log:**

> Sep 23, 2016 11:54:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
> log INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath:
> [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@6ac912e5,
> cien.ApplicationLoader@417f3e5b]
>
> Remote Tomcat Server log: Dec 14, 2016 4:39:43 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Spring
> WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath:
> [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@52aa77d9]

**Note:** The Application loader class is available in the `web_INF` folder.

Comment: Have you checked just production tomcat error log or have you checked also other production logs? If it is working on local instance of tomcat so it should lead you to double check config of production tomcat.

Comment: What do you mean by other production logs? I'm not getting your point..

Comment: The local Tomcat setup is  :
Tomcat 7.0.57
Java 1.8.92
Grails 3.1.6

Production Environment is quite different:
Tomcat 7.0.57
Java 1.7.76
Grails 3.1.6
Does the change on Java version makes any impact on this ? Becoz im building the war file in java 8 but deploying it in java 7 tomcat(production)

Comment: it may impact. try to be consistent.

Comment: just remember, if you build a war with java 8, then you cannot run war file with java 7.